# Gradle start new process / kill parent session

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

Background: Apparently, based on JIRA ticket below there are no options to run more than one `gradle` processes on the same project on the same cache:
https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1991

My build contains couple "tasks" that using `JavaExec` are starting new processes to do some job (not related to build itself).
I have more than one of such tasks, and I need to run them in parallel. But cause of issue above - can't

```
> Could not open buildscript class cache for build file 'C
rpd407vnbbns8c3t51r39r\ProjectScript\buildscript).
   > Timeout waiting to lock buildscript class cache for b...
     Owner PID: unknown
     Our PID: 15860
     Owner Operation: unknown
     Our operation: Initialize cache
```

What are my options?
Ideal solution for me is to run those processes without keeping parent process (let it finish). Is it possible?